# Simplest Mutex ever. Does this example work? Is it thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, global-variables, mutex

I would like to ask about the simplest Mutex approach ever for multi-threading. Is the following code thread-safe (quick-n-dirty)?

```
class myclass
{
    bool locked;
    vector<double> vals;

    myclass();
    void add(double val);
};

void myclass::add(double val)
{
    if(!locked)
    {
        this->locked = 1;
        this->vals.push_back(val);
        this->locked = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this->add(val);
    }
}

int main()
{
    myclass cls;
    //start parallelism
    cls.add(static_cast<double>(rand()));
}
```

Does this work? Is it thread-safe? I'm just trying to understand how the simplest mutex can be written.

If you have any advice about my example, would be nice.

Thank you.

Thanks for saying that it doesn't work. Can you please suggest a fix which is compiler independent?

Comment: Making a correct mutex mechanism is a complex business. I would use something already out there.

Comment: Generally, synchronization primitives such as mutexes require some atomicity (often at the CPU instruction level). Here's an interesting link I found: http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/1999-August/000457.html

Comment: The simplest mutex (or synchronization construct in general) is the one you don't need ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it thread-safe?

Certainly not. If a thread is preempted between checking and setting the lock, then a second thread could acquire that lock; if control then returns to the first thread, then both will acquire it. (And of course, on a modern processor, two or more cores could be executing the same instructions simultaneously for even more hilarity.)

At the very least, you need an atomic test-and-set operation to implement a lock like this. The C++11 library provides such a thing:

```
std::atomic_flag locked;

if (!locked.test_and_set()) {
    vals.push_back(val);
    locked.clear();
} else {
    // I don't know exactly what to do here; 
    // but recursively calling add() is a very bad idea.
}
```

or better yet:

```
std::mutex mutex;

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
vals.push_back(val);
```

If you have an older implementation, then you'll have to rely on whatever extensions/libraries are available to you, as there was nothing helpful in the language or standard library back then.

Comment: hmmmmm. Thanks for the answers. I'm using VS2010 and g++, where the first one doesn't support mutex. Any other compiler independent idea?

Comment: @SamerAfach: The [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) and [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) libraries have portable and (more or less) direct replacements for the C++11 mutex. Failing that there's the Windows API (critical sections, or whatever they call it); obviously that's not compiler-independent, so you'll need some carefully placed `#define`s to select which to use.

Comment: @MikeSymour if I use the boost Mutex for example (or any other Mutex), will that make the code thread-safe for other parallelization libraries, like OpenMPI and OpemMP? or does Mutex work exclusively for the parallelism of the library from which the Mutex is taken?

Comment: @SamerAfach: I don't quite understand the question, but I guess the answer is yes. Using a mutex correctly will serialise all sections of code that run with that mutex locked, making that code thread-safe, regardless of whatever parallelisation libraries you're using.

Comment: "regardless of whatever parallelisation libraries you're using". That answers my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not thread safe. There's a race between

```
if(!locked)
```

and

```
this->locked = 1;
```

If there is a context switch between these two statements, your lock mechanism falls apart. You need an atomic [`test and set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set) instruction, or simply use an existing [`mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Answer (score 6):

This code doesn't provide an atomic modification of `vals` vector. Consider the following scenario:

```
//<<< Suppose it's 0
if(!locked)
{   //<<< Thread 0 passes the check
    //<<< Context Switch - and Thread 1 is also there because locked is 0
    this->locked = 1;
    //<<< Now it's possible for one thread to be scheduled when another one is in
    //<<< the middle of modification of the vector
    this->vals.push_back(val);
    this->locked = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does this work? Is it thread-safe?

No.  It will fail at times.

Your mutex will only work if other threads **never** do anything between the execution of these two lines:

```
if(!locked)
{
    this->locked = 1;
```

...and you have not ensured that.

To learn about the *how* of mutex writing, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485924/how-are-mutexes-implemented).

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not thread safe.

Consider two threads running `myclass::add` at more-or-less the same time. Also, imagine that the value of `.locked` is `false`.

The first thread executes up to and including this line:

```
if(!locked)
{
```

Now imagine that the system switches context to the second thread. It also executes up to the same line.

Now we have two different threads, both believing that they have exclusive access, and both inside the `!locked` condition of the if.

They will both call `vals.push_back()` at more-or-less the same time.

Boom.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already shown how your mutex can fail, so I won't rehash their points. I will only add one thing: The *simplest* mutex implementation is a lot more complicated than your code.

If you're interested in the nitty gritty (or even if you are not - this is stuff *every* software developer should know) you should look at [Leslie Lamport's Bakery Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement it in C++. You have to use LOCK CMPXCHG. Here is my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485924/how-are-mutexes-implemented/54003648#54003648):

```
; BL is the mutex id
; shared_val, a memory address

CMP [shared_val],BL ; Perhaps it is locked to us anyway
JZ .OutLoop2
.Loop1:
CMP [shared_val],0xFF ; Free
JZ .OutLoop1 ; Yes
pause ; equal to rep nop.
JMP .Loop1 ; Else, retry

.OutLoop1:

; Lock is free, grab it
MOV AL,0xFF
LOCK CMPXCHG [shared_val],BL
JNZ .Loop1 ; Write failed

.OutLoop2: ; Lock Acquired
```